# How to detect class type and change in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where the first line is the header, the second line is some explanatory data, and then rows 3 on are  numbers. Because when I read in the data with this second explanatory row, the classes are automatically converted to factors (or I could put stringsasfactors=F).

What I would like to do is remove the second row, and have a function that goes through all columns and detects if they're just numbers and change the class type to the appropriate type. Is there something like that available? Perhaps using dplyr? I have many columns so I'd like to avoid manually reassigning them.

A simplified example below

```
> df <- data.frame(A = c("col 1",1,2,3,4,5), B = c("col 2",1,2,3,4,5))
> df
      A     B
1 col 1 col 2
2     1     1
3     2     2
4     3     3
5     4     4
6     5     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all the numbers are after the second line, then we can do so

```
library(tidyverse)
df[-1, ] %>% mutate_all(as.numeric)
```

depending on the task can be done this way

```
df <- tibble(A = c("col 1",1,2,3,4,5), 
                 B = c("col 2",1,2,3,4,5),
                 C = c(letters[1:5], 6))

df[-1, ] %>% mutate_if(~ any(!is.na(as.numeric(.))), as.numeric)
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1    NA
2     2     2    NA
3     3     3    NA
4     4     4    NA
5     5     5     6
```

or so

```
df[-1, ] %>% mutate_if(~ all(!is.na(as.numeric(.))), as.numeric)

      A     B C    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1 b    
2     2     2 c    
3     3     3 d    
4     4     4 e    
5     5     5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can just do

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.numeric)
```